# Batman 89' by Sam Hamm TPB

Tags: comics, batman, publishing

Does the following *Batman 89'* [Trade paper back](https://www.bookdepository.com/Batman-89-Sam-Hamm/9781779512680?ref=grid-view&qid=1679833150577&sr=1-1) by Sam Hamm contain the entire story arc (i.e. it has a closed ending)?

Comment: I don't know if it is the right place, but I read the TPB, and I was highly disappointed by it. The story does great injustice to Batman and presents him as almost useless. There are few action scenes and most of them are not of Batman, but of Robin and Catwoman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like [it contains all six issues](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_%2789_(Collected)).

> This trade paperback reprints the following issues:
>
> - Batman '89 #1: "Shadows, Chapter 1"
> - Batman '89 #2: "Shadows, Chapter 2"
> - Batman '89 #3: "Shadows, Chapter 3"
> - Batman '89 #4: "Shadows, Chapter 4"
> - Batman '89 #5: "Shadows, Chapter 5"
> - Batman '89 #6: "Shadows, Finale"

Comment: Also from [DC.com](https://www.dc.com/graphic-novels/batman-89) - "_Collects Batman '89 #1-6._"